# Presenting an ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, contentpresenter

simple question!

I want to present an itemscontrol inside of an expander and grid which contains a textbox. I want to do this multiple times so I wrapped it in a ControlTemplate.

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ArrayPresenter">
    <Expander Template="{StaticResource ArrayTemplate}">
        <Grid>
            <ContentPresenter/>
            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="Empty" Margin="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#66C9C9C9" FontSize="15" Visibility="{quickConverter:Binding '$P.Count == 0 ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed', P={Binding Array}}" />
        </Grid>
    </Expander>
</ControlTemplate>
```

This is what I want to present. Unfortunately whenever an item is added to the itemscontrol, nothing happens and it doens't display the new items!

```
<ContentControl Template="{StaticResource ArrayPresenter}">
        <ItemsControl Style="{StaticResource ArrayItemsStyle}" Margin="5" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource StructureFieldTemplate}"/>
    </ContentControl>
```

Comment: Did you try targeting type of your `ControlTemplate` like `<ControlTemplate ... TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">`?

Comment: Wow it was that simple - it must be time to go home. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment you need to target type of your `ControlTemplate`

```
<ControlTemplate ... TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
```

Without that `ControlTemplate` targets `System.Windows.Controls.Control` type and that does not have `Content` to present so `ContentPresenter` does not know what to show.

Comment: Thank you for your speedy response :).